# Using changes on branch B while working on branch A

Tags: git, version-control

I'm developing on branch A but I needed to fix something that is independent of the feature on branch A, so I made a fix on branch B to fix that.

The thing is that branch A still needs to use the change in branch B. How can I use this change without adding those commits to branch A. Ie when developing I would like to use the changes in branch B without having the commits in branch B also in branch A.

That way branch A and B can be reviewed separately once the PRs go up for review.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practice to develop two different but dependent tasks in separate branch. Usually if `task B` is dependent to `task A`, `task A` must be pushed before you start `task B`. Git provides branch option mostly to allow you to develop independent task simultaneously.

But you can switch branch to branch easily event when you are in the middle of development. Use following way,

```
$ git branch
      master
    * taskA
      taskB

# some modification for task A
$ git stash
$ git checkout taskB

$ git branch
      master
      taskA
    * taskB

# some modification for task A
$ git stash

$ git checkout taskA #back to taskA branch
$ git stash pop #pop the previous uncommitted works
# start finishing ...
```

Answer (score 0):

During developing of branch `A` you can take changes made in branch `B` using `rebase` and in this case all commits made in branch `A` will be above commits made in branch `B`, then after development of branch `A` will be finished you can remove commits that were copied from branch `B` using `rebase` with interactive mode and `drop` option.

---

**Copy commits made in branch `B` to branch `A` using `rebase`:**

```
git checkout `A`
git rebase `B`
```

---

**Remove commits made in branch `B` from branch `A` using `rebase -i`:**

```
git checkout `A`
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Where number `3` is total count of commits made in branch `A` and `B`.
In editor you will see all commits, for example we have two commits from branch `B` with messages `commit-branch-b1` and `commit-branch-b2` and one commit from branch `A` with message `commit-branch-a1`:

```
pick f533903 commit-branch-a1
pick c66cc92 commit-branch-b2
pick 647ab90 commit-branch-b1
```

Now to remove commits `commit-branch-b2` and `commit-branch-b1` we need to change word `pick` to `drop` near commit hashes:

```
pick f533903 commit-branch-a1
drop c66cc92 commit-branch-b2
drop 647ab90 commit-branch-b1
```

After that save changes and continue `rebase`, and as result commits `commit-branch-b2` and `commit-branch-b1` will be removed from branch `A`.